# HTML page will not respond to ID's in CSS

Tags: html, css

HTML and CSS noob running into my first problem.

I am using Notepad++ and I have my css and HTML files both saved in the same folder. But whenever I launch the HTML file in a browser the css ID that I am using is not doing anything specifically centering and changing color.

This seems like one of those easy fix kind of things.

**Main.css**

```
   <style>
   #change{color:red; text-align:center }
   </style>
```

**example.html**

```
<html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<Title>sample</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="folder/main.css" />
</head>

 <body>
 <p id="change">Sample sample sample </p>     //HERE IS WHERE THE ID IS
 </body>

  </html>
```

anyone have an idea what im doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

To combine the two current answers:

If the directory structure of your website is simply the index.html and main.css in the same folder, than the path to link the two is:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href"main.css"/>`

The Style tags in your current css page are redundant and unnecessary. Style tags could be used in the html, though are rarely used.

Finally, not sure if this is just the code you have posted, but the html here is acting as if it is all a comment,and make sure to delete that if that is in your current code (/*).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<style>` and `</style>` tags. Your *main.css* file should only contain CSS:

```css
#change{ color:red; text-align:center }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **check css path.**

Are paths like below?

```
- example.html
- folder/
 |-   main.css
```

2. **remove  tag in main.css**

In css files, any html tag **MUST NOT** be existed.

Answer (score 0):

and welcome to the world of web designing! Things can get quite frustrating, but as long as you show your will to solve a problem, everything will go smoothly. I love the fact that you tried to solve the problem prior to posting. Even though it is a basic thing, let's go step by step:

1. `main.css` does NOT need `<style>` tags. Those are only required when editing CSS internally, inside of `<head>` element of HTML page. In *.css files, you just start defining CSS rules.
2. make sure that you follow proper spacing like `#change { color: red; text-align: center; }` (ALWAYS FINISH A CSS RULE WITH A SEMI-COLON)

you can also break them down like this:

`#change { 
    color: red;
    text-align: center; 
}`

3. Characters `/*` and `*/` are CSS comments syntax. ANYTHING between those characters shall be ignored by the browser.
4. `<link rel="stylesheet"  href="folder/main.css" />` might potentially be the cause of the problem, since you stated that html file and css file are in the same folder. If that is the case, you don't need `"folder/main.css"` but only `href="main.css" />` Also it wouldn't hurt to add `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />` to let the browser know the type of the file you're linking to.

Here is a working example.

```css
#change {
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <Title>sample</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="folder/main.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <p id="change">Sample sample sample </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm well aware. It's just that I don't know whether I will add more rules to that particular selector, so I close it, just in case.